# Rotate an object and move up local z axis at the same time

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

I need to rotate these two objects around the same pivot point with the outer object sliding up it's local z axis and ending up inside the inner object. I have tried using a transformation constraint along with a copy rotation however the object gets moved up the z axis in world space (even after selecting local space in settings) which doesn't lead to my desired outcome. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

This is my setup with the constraints I thought would work:
[image: This is my setup with the constraints I thought would work]

Here is how the constraints work with undesired result:
[image: Here is how the constraints work with undesired result]

This is how I want the constraints to work, with the object rotating and moving up it's local z axis at the same time:
[image: This is how I want the constraints to work, with the object rotating and moving up the z axis at the same time]

Comment: I would suggest animating the position and change the constraint from loc to rot.

Comment: so why don't you parent object 1 to an empty (that will be the rotation center), parent the object 2 to object 1, then rotate the empty, object 1 will follow, then move object 2 along the desired local axis (G Z Z if it's Z)

Comment: I wanted a way to make it easier whilst editing to see the changes. I'm going to make it a bit more complex with more objects moving in between in a similar way. Basically I want to use the empty as a slider control that calculates and shows the positions automatically. Is there anyway of doing this without going into animation to make it easier for concepting. Apologies for my poor way of describing things.

Comment: in the case you show up above, object 1 parented to empty, object 2 parented to object 1, then Copy Transforms constraint for object 2 would work fine but I'm not sure it will work for all the cases you're planning to do

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me get it working how i wanted it to

Answer (score 1):

So what you can do is:

- Create your 2 objects. Create an empty where the rotation is supposed to happen. Parent object 1 to the empty, parent object 2 to object 1.

[image]

- Give object 2 a *Copy Transforms* constraint with object 1 as *Target*.

[image]